# Where to find a multiple translations list of common user interface words/phrases

Tags: internationalization

I am internationalizing my simple app. Is there a list of translations for simple words like: "CLOSE" "SAVE" "BACK" "SET LOCATION SERVICES TO 'ON' IN YOUR SETTINGS MENU" etc. (Google translate is not good enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Translate might not be up to the task - but google itself might just be...

Here's something I found within 9 seconds of searching!

ftp://cpe-212-85-172-64.cable.telemach.net/uros/Languages.txt

Comment: Very good start! A few more mobile app phrases and we are there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I have to go through the manuals to find official IOS "speak". Would be nice though if there was a list...  http://www.apple.com/support/country/?dest=manuals